# Can you encrypt in Swift without using padding? (Using AES256 and ECB)

Tags: swift, encryption

Trying to make an encryption method to communicate with PHP code. Is there a way I can create an AES256 w/ ECB encryption that does not have padding in Swift?

Edit: I want to encrypt something in Swift using AES 256 and ECB mode. I do not want to use any padding (i.e PKCS7) so it would be very similar to mcrypt on PHP. I cannot change my code to have this done without running into several errors. What I want to know if there are other ways to create this, or if it is not possible.

Comment: If you don't use padding, then you can't encrypt arbitrary messages (only those of a multiple of the block size). Perhaps you mean to say recreate the zero padding that is used by mcrypt? In any case, you shouldn't use ECB or mcrypt nowadays.

Comment: For me right, now I have no choice but to use them (long story). But, yes, if I could recreate that kind of padding, it would be perfect.

Comment: If you just want 0 padding, measure your byte length of the plain text and calculate that number mod 16.  Because AES block size is always 16 bytes (128 bits) regardless of key size.  Now you know how many bytes of the final block have real information.  Add enough zeros to make it an even multiple of 16, so the whole byte length mod 16 is 0.  Then encrypt like that and decrypt on the other side.  Unlike PKCS7 padding, 0 based padding has no built-in way to let you know what is padding and what are real 0s at the end of the actual message.  But it should work at least.

Comment: I've voted to close this question. There are Swift AES libraries out there. After that it's a question of implementing the zero padding of PHP. Please try this yourself and ask a question when you become stuck, including both the PHP and the Swift code, and a single concise question.

Comment: This line of code:
            CCOptions = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode | kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)
I want to do this with zero padding, but I am having a hard time figuring it out.